# How to fetch data from sanity to Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'm new to sanity and data fetching in Nextjs but I'm familiar in axios and fetch method.

How do you guys fetch your data from your deployed Sanity project?

Here, I tried to fetch my data but it returns "undefined".

```
const client = sanityClient({
projectId: "hmrph9hs",
dataset: "production",
  apiVersion: "2021-03-25", // use current UTC date - see "specifying API version"!
  useCdn: true, // `false` if you want to ensure fresh data
});
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
  const data = await client.fetch(`*[_type == "projects"]{
    title
   }`);

  return {
    props: { data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}
//My Component that will use the props.
```

Comment: Everything looks like it should work. Are you finding that `data` is undefined in your component? Make sure you've included it as an argument, either as `props` or by destructuring `data` (e.g., `export default function YourComponent({ data }) { // ...`).

Comment: https://github.com/sanity-io/example-frontend-next-js . Refer this example repo